# How to get id from the url react for dispatch instead of using params?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm trying to retrieve product id from the url and pass it to the function. I've tried to use useParams but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

I think match.params.id working with react router v5 and they changed it in v6.

Here is my ProductDetails.js

```
import React, { useEffect} from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useAlert } from 'react-alert';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux' 
import { getProductDetails, clearErrors } from '../../actions/productActions'

const ProductDetails = ({match}) => {

    let params = useParams();

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const alert = useAlert();

    const { loading, error, product } = useSelector(state => state.productDetails);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));

        if(error){
            alert.error(error);
            dispatch(clearErrors());
        }

    }, [dispatch, alert, error, match.params.id]);
```

Comment: You posted `ProductDetails.js` twice, please fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the `id` directly with:

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

And then use it with:

```
dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
```